# String is printing weird characters - c code in lex

Tags: c, string, char, lex, dynamic-allocation

Below is a C code in lex. I have three input strings which is shown below. The first two prints out properly. At the end of the third input string, there are two weird characters that gets printed. I know this is because of the null character. But my code takes care of it and it doesn't happen with my first two input strings.

1st input string : (c,a,b,ma,mb,low)
2nd input string : (c,a,b,ma,mb+1,low)
3rd input string : (c,data, istart, mid,BASE)

When the code is executed func_initial_var will contain "(" according to the string and func_var will contain the rest of the string.

The problem is only with third input string. Suppose if I add two extra characters at the end of third string, it prints properly which I guess there are two extra spaces that gets allocated. My question is why only in the third input string? Why not in the first two? Please help. This is been bugging me since yesterday morning. Thanks.

```
    char *func_var = "";
    char *func_initial_var = "";

<SOME_STATE>.       { char c;
                    func_initial_var = strdup(yytext);
                    c = input();
                    func_var = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char));
                    for(q=0;;q++) {
                        if(c == ')')
                        {
                          func_var[q] = c;
                          printf("%s\n",func_var);
                          BEGIN SOME_STATE_X;
                          break;
                        }
                    func_var[q] = c;
                    printf("%s\n",func_var);
                    temp_func = (char*) realloc(func_var,(q+2)*sizeof(char));
                    if(temp_func != NULL) 
                        {
                        func_var = temp_func;
                        } else {
                      free(func_var);
                      printf("Error allocating memory\n");
                      return 1;
                        }
                    c = input();
                      }
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try allocating more memory, something like:

func_var = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)* strlen(func_initial_var));

in your code youŕe allocating 4 bytes (sizeof char)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried doing it, Still the same result. I have to change only in line number 4 right?

Comment: Do you have any idea why those are getting printed? @pmoretti

Comment: Maybe you have problems with printf, as it hadles null terminated array of chars, try adding a '\0' at next position of func_var[q].

Answer (score 0):

This has remained unclosed for a while now, but the hints of the answer are in the comments. The question is not about lex/flex. Its just a problem understanding the differences between characters, arrays of characters and strings in **C**. From the coding errors made the question indicates the confusion the beginners have in understanding those differences when coding using character pointers and arrays of characters. A summary might help indicate some of the points of confusion.

Let's look, in diagram form, these structures in **C**:

**A single character might look like this:**

```
           .---.
char c;    | c |
           `---'
```

**An array of two characters might look like this:**

```
           .----.----.
char c[2]; |c[0]|c[1]|
           `----'----'
```

**A string of two characters might look like this:**

```
           .---.  .----.----.---.
char *s;   | s--->|s[0]|s[1]|0x0|
           `---'  `----'----'---'
```

**A string containing a single character might look like this:**

```
           .---.  .----.---.
char *s;   | s--->|s[0]|0x0|
           `---'  `----'---'
```

As a consequence, when a character or an array of characters is copied to a string or being converted to be used as a string it will be longer than the equivalent non-string because of the terminating *null byte*. The *null byte* is there because a string is a variable length construct. It indicates the end of the string. Using this knowledge, the original example can be amended to use the correct storage length and also place the string terminators in their correct places:

```
%{
    char *func_var = "";
    char *func_initial_var = "";
    char *temp_func;
    static int q;
    #include <string.h>
%}
%s SOME_STATE_X
%%
<INITIAL>.       { char c;
                    func_initial_var = strdup(yytext);
                    c = input();
                    func_var = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)+1);
                    for(q=0;;q++) {
                        if(c == ')')
                        {
                          func_var[q] = c;
                          func_var[q+1] = 0;
                          printf("%s\n",func_var);
                          BEGIN SOME_STATE_X;
                          break;
                        }
                    func_var[q] = c;
                    func_var[q+1] = 0;
                    printf("%s\n",func_var);
                    temp_func = (char*) realloc(func_var,(q+2)*sizeof(char)+1);
                    if(temp_func != NULL) 
                        {
                        func_var = temp_func;
                        } else {
                      free(func_var);
                      printf("Error allocating memory\n");
                      return 1;
                        }
                    c = input();
                      }
                    }
```

This code now runs and generates the following, for the example test case:

```
(c,data, istart, mid,BASE)
c
c,
c,d
c,da
c,dat
c,data
c,data,
c,data,
c,data, i
c,data, is
c,data, ist
c,data, ista
c,data, istar
c,data, istart
c,data, istart,
c,data, istart,
c,data, istart, m
c,data, istart, mi
c,data, istart, mid
c,data, istart, mid,
c,data, istart, mid,B
c,data, istart, mid,BA
c,data, istart, mid,BAS
c,data, istart, mid,BASE
c,data, istart, mid,BASE)
```

Now the code is probably not the best way to use the `lex` tool, but this is not  `lex` tutorial!